# a loop that checks whether each row of the matrix S contains

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I need to write a loop that checks whether each row of the matrix S contains **each** of the numbers 1,2,3,...,9
The output for the following matrix should be one single TRUE:

```
S <- matrix(
    c(4,3,5,6,1,2,7,8,9,
    6,2,7,9,5,8,4,3,1,
    9,8,1,7,4,3,2,6,5,
    1,4,2,3,8,7,5,9,6,
    8,6,9,4,2,5,1,7,3,
    7,5,3,1,6,9,8,4,2,
    3,9,8,2,7,1,6,5,4,
    5,1,6,8,9,4,3,2,7,
    2,7,4,5,3,6,9,1,8), 
    9, 9, byrow = TRUE
)
```

My code looks like following at the moment:

```
for (i in 1:9) {
    sudoku <- c(1:9 %in% S[i,]) 
    print (TRUE)
}
```

However, like this I can't check if each of the numbers appear in each of the rows. Do you have any ideas how I could move on with this problem?

Comment: Do you mean like `all(apply(S, 1, function(x) all(1:9 %in% x)))`?

Comment: Maybe `all(apply(S,1,table) == 1)`

Comment: Big help nrussell, yes, that's it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nrussell, why you (or people in general) don't post there answer as an answer rather than a comment? when you only post a comment the question can't be closed... and other people click on this question to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all(apply(S, 1, is.element, el=c(1:9)))
```